# What is an alternate of ionic zip in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, zip

I use Ionic.Zip to zip and unzip my data. But I find that Ionic.Zip is not capable of handling large file sizes (> 3GB).

So is there any third party tool that we can use to replace Ionic.Zip?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you can use .NET Framework 4.5+, [ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive) is now part of the BCL, as described by the "[What's New in the .NET 4.5 Base Class Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/june/clr-what%E2%80%99s-new-in-the-net-4-5-base-class-library#support-for-zip-archives)" article.

Also, IMHO the 'de facto' third-party library for this is [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) from the SharpDevelop team.

Answer (score 14):

It can actually handle larger files.

For that you need to use property:

```
UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.Always
```

Answer (score 0):

[Xceed realtimes zip for .NET](http://xceed.com/ZipRT_Net_Intro.html)

Quote from their website:

> The size or number of files in a Zip archive has absolutely no impact on memory and disk-space requirements.

Might be cheaper options out there.

Comment: i ve gone through some forums and they say that the ionic zip uses multiple threads or buffers(some stuffs like that) during the save process..The issue i face here is i am able to zip contents in my user machine but with machines running multiple applications ionic zip fails to save the zipped file...Exception is "system.outofmemory"

Answer (score 0):

[System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx) Namespace has [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) and [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) classes.